# Overflowing a container div horizontally but not vertically

Tags: html, css, overflow

I'm working on a website that uses two columns inside a container. The container has a white background that should stretch to the bottom of whichever column is highest, so I'm using the [holy grail](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/holygrail/) method for that.

However, both columns should positioned so that a part of it exceeds the white background ([this example](http://jsfiddle.net/je8aS/2/) uses a fixed height, which should be fluid). As far as I know, this can only be done by setting the overflow to visible but this break the equal height of the columns.

How do I fix this with as little additional elements as possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest fix in this case seems to be adding [`<br style="clear:both" />`](http://jsfiddle.net/je8aS/3/) before the closing tag for `#container`.

You can change it to `<br class="clearfix" />` and `.clearfix{clear:both}` if you wish.

Comment: Wow, it was that easy? I've always done my best to avoid empty clearfix elements (99% of the time there's a more elegant solution) but this is obviously the exception to that rule. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Solution is to use `inline-block` elements..

**Css**

```
.container{
    width:300px;
    background-color:#ccc;
    margin:0 auto;
    border:1px solid red;
}
.container > div{
    width:150px;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}
.inner{
    background-color:#666;
    margin-top:10px;
    width:130px;
}
.left .inner{
    margin-left:-10px;
}
.right .inner{
    margin-right:-10px;
    margin-left:auto;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="left">
        <div class="inner">left 1st inner panel</div>
        <div class="inner">left 2nd inner panel</div>
    </div><div class="right">
        <div class="inner">right 1st inner panel</div>
        <div class="inner">right 2nd inner panel with arbitrary text to show the increase in parent elements</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**[view demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/CrHQE/)**

Comment: The other answer already worked, but +1 for the nice solution. Unfortunately I still have to support IE7 (no 6 thank god), which can't handle inline-blocks real well.

Comment: @Stephan, thank god for IE6 getting finally out of the picture.. In regards to IE7 and `inline-block` have a look at http://www.brunildo.org/test/InlineBlockLayout.html Just for future options ;)